# Any way to set lockscreen notifications on AT&T LG G3 Lollipop?

Tags: notifications, lock-screens, 5.0-lollipop, lg-g3

AT&T appears to have completely disabled the lockscreen notification settings in their LG G3 Lollipop update. Anyone know of any way to change which notifications are shown, which are sensitive, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to **Settings -> Sound**, and scroll down to the **Notifications** category.
The **Lock Screen** selection allows to choose Hide sensitive only, show all, or hide all. The **Apps** selection is a list of apps, which will let you select app behavior. However, the sensitive option is only available if you select "Show all notifications" option above.
Additionally it appears some applications have an invisible sensitivity setting that allows them to display information when "Hide sensitive only" is selected. I have several apps on my phone that display info/controls when the screen is locked, and I have it set to "Hide sensitive only" I found some discussion of the above information on this site, but nothing to explain the fact that some apps seem to default to nonsensitive, most don't.